# Ping Identity SSO error with spring SAML project

Tags: single-sign-on, ping, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am having trouble figuring out what the problem is! I have following simple configuration:

Any help will be appreciated!

2020-02-03 18:25:23.760 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider       : Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider       : Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider       : Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document did not contain a descriptor for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Metadata document does not contain a role of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor supporting protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider       : Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of com:hf:pingidentity:sp
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver     : Building credential from keystore entry for entityID spring, usage type UNSPECIFIED
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver     : Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] .c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry : Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver     : Building credential from keystore entry for entityID spring, usage type UNSPECIFIED
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.x.s.c.KeyStoreCredentialResolver     : Processing PrivateKeyEntry from keystore
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] .c.c.EvaluableCredentialCriteriaRegistry : Registry located evaluable criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.criteria.EvaluableEntityIDCredentialCriteria for criteria class org.opensaml.xml.security.criteria.EntityIDCriteria
2020-02-03 18:25:23.761 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.x.p.StaticBasicParserPool            : Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing'
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.x.p.StaticBasicParserPool            : Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion'
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.x.p.StaticBasicParserPool            : Setting DocumentBuilderFactory attribute 'http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl'
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.s.s.s.c.SAMLContextProviderImpl        : Using user specified IDP https://athenanet.athenahealth.com from request
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.ChainingMetadataProvider       : Checking child metadata provider for entity descriptor with entity ID: https://athenanet.athenahealth.com
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.p.AbstractMetadataProvider       : Searching for entity descriptor with an entity ID of https://athenanet.athenahealth.com
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.s.s.s.u.SAMLUtil                       : Index for AssertionConsumerService not specified, returning default
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.s.SAML2MetadataHelper            : Selecting default IndexedEndpoint
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.o.s.m.s.SAML2MetadataHelper            : Selected IndexedEndpoint with explicit isDefault of true
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.s.s.s.SAMLEntryPoint                   : Processing SSO using WebSSO profile
2020-02-03 18:25:23.762 DEBUG 10609 --- [nio-5001-exec-8] o.s.s.s.SAMLEntryPoint                   : Error initializing entry point

org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: No supported binding null was found for profile urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:SSO:browser
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl.getSingleSignOnService(WebSSOProfileImpl.java:151) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl.sendAuthenticationRequest(WebSSOProfileImpl.java:89) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.initializeSSO(SAMLEntryPoint.java:225) ~[spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.commence(SAMLEntryPoint.java:152) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:106) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87) [spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) [spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.24.jar!/:9.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]

Comment: `Metadata document did not contain any role descriptors of type {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor for entity com:hf:pingidentity:sp ` I find it a bit strange that your Ping Federate entity should act as a Service Provider. Spring SAML implements the Service Provider side and Ping should be the IdP.

Comment: Ping is IDP, and SP is my server (the logs here are on my server when I try to initiate SAML flow from SP

Comment: `Ping is IDP, and SP `. This is what I suspected, but the log tells a different story. You may post your Spring SAML config.